# Null characters added when a string is encoded into UTF-8 bytes?

Tags: java, character-encoding

The code snippet:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "qwertyuiop";
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Charset
       .forName("UTF-8")
       .encode(s)
       .array()));
}
```

Prints:

```
[113, 119, 101, 114, 116, 121, 117, 105, 111, 112, 0]
```

That seems to happen because, under the hood, averageBytesPerChar variable appears to be 1.1 for UTF-8 inside java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder class. Hence it allocates 11 bytes instead of 10 and, provided the input string contains only good old single byte chars, I get that odd null character in the end.

I wonder if this is documented anywhere?

This page:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#encode(java.lang.String)

Doesn't give a clue about such behaviour.

P. S. Do I get it right that in any case the snippet above would better be replaced by:

```
s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```

Which as I see from its source also trims the result in order to avoid those null chars?

Then, what the java.nio.charset.Charset's encode(String s) is supposed to be for?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### The problem is not in `Charset.encode()`, but `Buffer.array()`.

If you printed `Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode(s)`, you will find the output to be

```
java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=10 cap=11]
```

The ByteBuffer has limit 10, the length of the string, and *capacity* 11, the total allocated size of the buffer. If you change the encoding the limit and capacity may have even wilder variation, e.g.

```
System.out.println(Charset.forName("UTF-16").encode(s));
// java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=22 cap=41]
// (2 extra bytes because of the BOM, not null-termination)
```

When you [call `.array()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#array()), it will return the whole  backing array, so even stuff beyond the limit will be included.

The actual method to extract a Java byte array is through [the `.get()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#get(byte[])):

```
ByteBuffer buf = Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode(s);
byte[] encoded = new byte[buf.limit()];
buf.get(encoded);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(encoded));
```

Well this looks like a mess? Because "nio" means **N**ative **I/O**. The Buffer type is created so that it can easily wrap a C array. It makes interacting with native code such as reading/writing file or sending/receiving network data very efficient. These NIO APIs typically take a `Buffer` directly, without constructing any `byte[]` in between. If you are only working with `Buffer`, the middle two lines do not need to exist :).

If the whole operation stays within Java, yes just call `s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to see the byte array of your String encoded as UTF8 then simply use [getBytes(Charset charset)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes(java.nio.charset.Charset)) method. It may look something like this:

```
String hello = "qwertyuiop";   
byte[] helloBytes_UTF_8 = hello.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

You will see that there are 2 bytes per character. your output conforms to `StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1` charset. If you want to play more with different encodings then I would recommend to use a small open source library with some utils, one of which allows you co convert Strings into UNICODE (UTF-8) representation and back. [Open Source Java library with stack trace filtering, Silent String parsing Unicode converter and Version comparison](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/open-source-java-library-some-useful-utilities-michael-gantman). This article describes the library and how to use it.You can download the sources and javadoc as well. In particular look for paragraph "**String Unicode converter**". Using this class you will get your String `"qwertyuiop"` converted into: `"\u0071\u0077\u0065\u0072\u0074\u0079\u0075\u0069\u006f\u0070"` Each four digits after \u symbol represent 2 bytes (one character) in hexadecimal representation.